# Sync playlist to iPod on other networked iMac

Tags: itunes

I have a main iMac with an iTunes library that I share with Apple TV and an iMac my kids use. I want my kids to be able to plug in their iPod and sync it with a playlist I have set up, but the playlists don't appear as options on their computer, even though they can see and play them through the shared library. How am I supposed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

iPod/iPhone syncing only work with local files, meaning you have to copy your files to your kids computer or have them sync at yours (yes, it's a pain both ways).

Home Sharing somewhat helps here because it allows to copy purchased stuff automatically as explained in [HT3819](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819):

> You can also choose to have iTunes automatically import purchases you make on any of your Home Sharing computers to your own library. To do so, select the library and use the Settings button at the lower right of the iTunes window to check what you'd like copied.